# Using var() to instantiate object from user input. Syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error, var

I've made these classes and now I'm trying to make a function that allows you to instantiate a new object from data a user inputs. But I'm getting syntax errors with using var()

The class structure is that there is one main with two sub-classes. The main, "Gokemon" is:

```
class Gokemon:
    def __init__(self,NAME,TYPE,HEALTH,POWER): #Contructor #Mayb think about using dict key words
        self._Name = str(NAME)
        self._Type = str(TYPE) #Water, Earth, Fire or Flying. Used in Battle() to allow adders
        self._HP = int(HEALTH) #Health Points
        self._DP = int(POWER) #Power Points - attacking power
```

and the two sub-classes are named "Tame" and "Wild".

```
class Tame(Gokemon):
    def __init__(self,NAME,TYPE,HEALTH,POWER):
        Gokemon.__init__(self,NAME,TYPE,HEALTH,POWER)
        self._Owner = ""
        self._Time = 0 #How long have they owned it

class Wild(Gokemon):
    def __init__(self,NAME,TYPE,HEALTH,POWER):
        Gokemon.__init__(self,NAME,TYPE,HEALTH,POWER)
```

The function for making the new object by user input is as follows:

```
 def NewGokemon():
        n = input("What's its name?: ")
        while True:
            t = input("what's its type?: ")
            if t == "Water" or t == "Fire" or t=="Earth" or t =="Flying":
                break
            else:
                print("please try again, the types include:\nFire\nWater\nEarth\nFlying")
        while True:
            h = input("How many Health Points(HP) does it have")
            try:
                int(h)/2
            except ValueError:
                print("Sorry please input a numerical value")
            else:
                break
        while True:
            p = input("How many Health Points(HP) does it have")
            try:
                int(p)/2
            except ValueError:
                print("Sorry please input a numerical value")
            else:
                break
        while True:
            dom  = input("Is the Gokemon tame(input t) or wild(input w)?")
            if dom =="t":
                return var()[n] = Tame(n,t,h,p) 
            if dom == 'w':

                return var()[n] = Wild(n,t,h,p)
```

The function is fine until at the bottom, when im compiling to execute my Editor (VS code) says.

```
  File "c:\Users\rufar\Desktop\python\little projects\Gokemon - learning class\Gokemon.py", line 38
    return var()[n] = Tame(n,t,h,p) 
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. What do you expect for assignment of `var()[n]`? And what is `var()`?

Comment: I'm trying to make the name the user has input become the identifier for the object. i was reading on ways to create variables and i found "var".

Comment: **and just realised that i said "var" instead of "vars", and it isnt in the bracket. But when I amend all that the syntax error still pops up**

Comment: Never mind, I solved the problem. used globals instead of vars.

Answer (score 0):

replaced the whole bit with vars() with this:

```
   while True:
            dom  = input("Is the Gokemon tame(input t) or wild(input w)?")
            if dom =="t":
                globals()[n] = Tame(n,t,h,p)
                return n 
            elif dom == 'w':
                globals()[n] = Wild(n,t,h,p)
                return n
            else:
                print("Did not understand input")
```

And now it works fine.